# How to specify custom CPU requirement in SLURM?

Tags: cpu, jobs, slurm, hpc, lsf

I'm new to slurm and trying to figure out a way on how to run a job on specific CPUs of different Nodes. For example, I want my job to run on CPU0, CPU1 of Node a and CPU0,CPU2,CPU4,CPU6 of another Nodeb. How can I specify such requirements?
Thanks in Advance for any help.

Cpu-per-task and other similar constraint doesn't seem to fulfil the requirement

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible from Slurm. You may need to allocate the entire node, and then you can yourself specify e.g. with numactl which cores your application should run on.